# Create PDF file from html ajax form in php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a simple contact form. It sends email via AJAX. Works fine.

Now I need to create PDF file from results of this form and download it to user like [here](http://daveismyname.blog/demos/formpdf/)

**So html form:**

```
<form id="contact-form">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="contact_send" />
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your name..." />
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Your email..." />
    <textarea name="message" placeholder="Your message..."></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Send Message" />
</form>
```

**In functions.php I have function to send email:**

```
function sendContactFormToSiteAdmin () {

  try {
    if (empty($_POST['name']) || empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['message'])) {
      throw new Exception('Bad form parameters. Check the markup to make sure you are naming the inputs correctly.');
    }
    if (!is_email($_POST['email'])) {
      throw new Exception('Email address not formatted correctly.');
    }

    $subject = 'Contact Form: '.$reason.' - '.$_POST['name'];
    $headers = 'From: My Blog Contact Form <contact@myblog.com>';
    $send_to = "contact@myblog.com";
    $subject = "MyBlog Contact Form ($reason): ".$_POST['name'];
    $message = "Message from ".$_POST['name'].": \n\n ". $_POST['message'] . " \n\n Reply to: " . $_POST['email'];

    if (wp_mail($send_to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
      echo json_encode(array('status' => 'success', 'message' => 'Contact message sent.'));
      exit;
    } else {
      throw new Exception('Failed to send email. Check AJAX handler.');
    }
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    echo json_encode(array('status' => 'error', 'message' => $e->getMessage()));
    exit;
  }


}
add_action("wp_ajax_contact_send", "sendContactFormToSiteAdmin");
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_contact_send", "sendContactFormToSiteAdmin");
```

**So in footer.php i have a script ajax handler:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('#contact-form').submit(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default form submit
      var $this = $(this); // Cache this
      $.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo admin_url("admin-ajax.php") ?>', // Let WordPress figure this url out...
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'JSON', // Set this so we don't need to decode the response...
        data: $this.serialize(), // One-liner form data prep...
        beforeSend: function () {},
        error: handleFormError,
        success: function (data) {
          if (data.status === 'success') {
           handleFormSuccess();
          } else {
            handleFormError(); // If we don't get the expected response, it's an error...
          }
        }
      });
    });
});
```

All of it works great. But i don't understand where i have to paste code for creation PDF, i have tried to paste it in `sendContactFormToSiteAdmin` php function, but it didn't work.

As in [this example](https://daveismyname.blog/create-pdf-with-form-data) i need to paste this code exactly in `sendContactFormToSiteAdmin` php function:

```
ob_start();
?>

<h1>Data from form</h1>
<p>Name: <?php echo $name;?></p>
<p>Email: <?php echo $email;?></p>

<?php 
$body = ob_get_clean();
$body = iconv("UTF-8","UTF-8//IGNORE",$body);
include("mpdf/mpdf.php");
$mpdf=new \mPDF('c','A4','','' , 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0); 
$mpdf->WriteHTML($body);
$mpdf->Output('demo.pdf','D');
```

But i don't understand how to do this with ajax response.

**Edit**
As Shoaib Zafar commented, if it is possible to email pdf file as an attachment to email, of course for me it is the best.

Comment: I don't understand clearly. Do you want to email the pdf as an attachment?

Comment: @Shoaib Zafar, If it possible, of course! in mPDF there is a possibility to write this file on server... I assumed to download this to client and save to server. But if it real possible to email the pdf as an attachment, of course i need it

Answer (score 0):

To email the PDF as an attachment, you need to alter your email sending function.

```
function sendContactFormToSiteAdmin () {

  try {
    if (empty($_POST['name']) || empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['message'])) {
      throw new Exception('Bad form parameters. Check the markup to make sure you are naming the inputs correctly.');
    }
    if (!is_email($_POST['email'])) {
      throw new Exception('Email address not formatted correctly.');
    }

ob_start();
?>
<h1>Data from form</h1>
<p>Name: <?php echo $_POST['name'];?></p>
<p>Email: <?php echo $_POST['email'];?></p>
<?php 
$body = ob_get_clean();
// Supposing you have already included ("mpdf/mpdf.php");
$mpdf=new \mPDF('c','A4','','' , 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0); 
$mpdf->WriteHTML($body);
$pdf_content = $mpdf->Output('', 'S');
$pdf_content = chunk_split(base64_encode($pdf_content));
$uid = md5(uniqid(time()));
$filename = 'contact.pdf';

    $subject = 'Contact Form: '.$reason.' - '.$_POST['name'];
    $message = "Message from ".$_POST['name'].": \n\n ". $_POST['message'] . " \n\n Reply to: " . $_POST['email'];
    $header = 'From: My Blog Contact Form <contact@myblog.com>';

$header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
$header .= "Content-type:text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
$header .= $message."\r\n\r\n";
$header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"\r\n\r\n";  
$header .= "Content-Type: application/pdf; name=\"".$filename."\"\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"\r\n\r\n";
$header .= $pdf_content."\r\n\r\n";
$header .= "--".$uid."--";

    $send_to = "contact@myblog.com";
    $subject = "MyBlog Contact Form ($reason): ".$_POST['name'];

    if (wp_mail($send_to, $subject, $message, $header)) {
      echo json_encode(array('status' => 'success', 'message' => 'Contact message sent.'));
      exit;
    } else {
      throw new Exception('Failed to send email. Check AJAX handler.');
    }
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    echo json_encode(array('status' => 'error', 'message' => $e->getMessage()));
    exit;
  }


}
```

I don't know much about how wp_email function work but technically this code should work, you only need to refactor it.
And you can also find this in the official documentation to learn more about it [mPDF Example #3](https://mpdf.github.io/reference/mpdf-functions/output.html)

Comment: Zafarthe, email contents "1ы,j Ў­zЫQzrЖ^Вл^Вкю эz{CЪhВ+bЂv­ЕЇ!щэ~)^Љ" without attachment=)

Comment: hmm maybe EOL issue .. just googled and seems like wp_mail uses 4th param for the attachment file. For this, you can save the file in some directory and use it as the attachment. See this gist i made for you. https://gist.github.com/mszb/994754f9db66ba533f361146780e8efd